# Linux Cat mutt emails from maildir

Tags: mutt

I have managed to link a gmail account up with offlineimap and mutt. I have a script that runs and I want to read and check my new emails. Is there a way for me to do something like cat /path/to/mutt/emails | grep "text search"?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do with that command. What does `cat /path/to/mutt/emails` output?

Comment: @dan08 I would like to be able to parse the emails contents. Current cat doesn't do anything, because (i think) the email is a Maildir file and isn't just a plain text file that you can just output.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.mutt.org/doc/devel/manual.html#patterns . I don't know much about mutt. I thought you were just missing something simple like: `cat /path/to/mutt/emails | xargs grep "text search"`

Answer (score 1):

Provided you are using the [Maildir](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/Maildir) format to store the mail locally, your email will be stored one email per file. You cannot do a simple cat in this case. You would need to find the email files first, using for example `find`. The Maildir format also defines to folders *cur* and *new*, so you could do something like this:

```
find <path-to-your-maildir>/new -type f | xargs grep "text search"
```

That might be helpful, when doing some low level scripts or when debugging the mail setup. However, I am also wondering why you would do it this way. Mutt has a very powerful search and tag syntax (much better than anything provided by a GUI mail client) - http://www.mutt.org/doc/devel/manual.html#patterns. Searches in email bodies can slow things down of course, depending of the size of your mailbox. For these cases there are external tools which can be integrated into mutt and fulltext index your emails, so that searches within the email bodies are much faster. Personally I am using *mu*, but there are alternatives - http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/UseCases/SearchingMail

Comment: going to try this in a little bit but i think this is what I am looking for